# C# LINQ Query Average

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var temp = 
from allData in result
group result by new { study = allData.study, groupNumber = allData.groupNumber } into grp
select new
{
   study = grp.Key.study,
   groupNumber = grp.Key.groupNumber,
   Average = grp.Average(c => c.ValueToAverage)
};
```

result is another LINQ query anonymous type.  I can't figure out why the average function will not work?  result has a data member call TGI, which is what I want to get the average for?  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to average `TGI`, why are you using `ValueToAverage`? What's actually happening? You say it won't work, but you haven't said what's going on now...

Comment: Sorry Jon, I just used that value as a generic example.  When I do c.(whatever value), I do not get a list of the data members, instead I get the list of LINQ functions.

Comment: Ah... I've got it now. Giving an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
group result by ...
```

should be:

```
group allData by ...
```

Otherwise your "element" for the group is actually *all* the results, not the element you're looking at.

It should be fine at that point. If not, please give a short but *complete* example.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Something I really should have noticed. I blame this weather and being stuck inside a fish bowl!!